# JS wait for subscription results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the best way to wait on the results of a subscription where I am passing in a callback.  For example let's say I have the following:

```
function someMethod() {
  let someResult = null;
  someSubPub.subscribe(someTopic, someKey, someValue, (someResponse) => {
     someResult = //do stuff in the callback with someResponse
  });
  return someResult;
}
```

I'm not quite sure how await would correctly work in this situation, aka blocking inside a callback.

Comment: when you get the result your callback will be called. What do you mean by wait?

Comment: I am trying to return someResult from the method.  Without blocking somehow, someResult would be null since the subscribe wouldnt happen until some later point.

Comment: The sub/pub SDK you're using may already support promises, in which case you can  make your function async, return the pub/sub promise, and await the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async/Await are nice, but sometimes it's simpler to think about the `Promise` construct that `async`/`await` abstracts away.

I suggest:

```
function someMethod() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      someSubPub.subscribe(someTopic, someKey, someValue, () => {
         const someResult = //do stuff in the callback
         resolve(someResult);
      });
  });
}
```

If you don't want to work with promises directly, you can wrap `someSubPub.subscribe` to return a promise

```
function someSubPubSubscribePromise(topic, key, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    someSubPub.subscribe(topic, key, value, resolve);
  });
}
async function someMethod() {
  await someSubPubSubscribePromise(someTopic, someKey, someValue);
  const someResult = //do stuff in the callback
  return someResult;
}
```

In either of those examples, you can do `const result = await someMethod()` (you can `await` both `async` methods and regular methods that return a promise)

---

One thing to consider: usually a pub/sub interface can call the callback multiple times. An async method / a method returning a promise can only resolve or reject exactly once. Probably you should be unsubscribing in the callback after you've responded to the event once?

Comment: Thanks for the examples, that makes sense!

Comment: Yep ! I was about to answer the same !